# As one moves with uniform speed in de Sitter space, does he experience blueshift of the de Sitter radiation?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, hawking-radiation

All objects in de Sitter space experience de Sitter radiation from the space boundary (which is spherical). What happens if one moves uniformly in one direction? Logic says, de Sitter radiation should not change for an inertial observer, but why?